# "Leader's Workshop" or "Leaders' Workshop"?

Tags: apostrophe, saxon-genitive

Leader's Workshop

or

Leaders' Workshop

Which is correct? A team of twenty leaders will be attending the workshop.

Comment: Since these people are attending rather than hosting the workshop, there is no issue of 'ownership' and so Leaders Workshop is probably the preferred version nowadays (a workshop aimed at rather than owned by the leaders).

Answer (score 1):

Leader's workshop is the workshop of one leader, Leaders' workshop is the workshop of some leaders. Both contain ambiguities (ownership does not imply content), and both can be argued to mean what i suspect it means, namely a workshop that is attended by, and tailored for, leaders.

How about Leadership workshop?

Comment: Thanks. Initially, I used Leadership. Then changed to Leaders'.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanics run the workshop, but we would call it a Motor workshop or car workshop. In the same manner, although the leaders are conducting the workshop, it deals with leadership and therefore in my opinion it is alright to call Leadership Workshop.

Comment: No, leaders are not conducting the workshop. The workshop I designed is for training the leaders. How can I title that?